# Вывести первую цифру числа

Tags: golang

Дано неотрицательное целое число. Найдите и выведите первую цифру числа.

Формат входных данных: На вход дается натуральное число, не превосходящее 10000.

Формат выходных данных: Выведите одно целое число - первую цифру заданного числа.

Sample Input:

```
1234
```

Sample Output:

```
1
```

Вот мой код:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a int
    fmt.Print("Введите число: ")
    fmt.Scan(&a)
    if a < 10000 {
        a = a / 100 / 10
        fmt.Println(a)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Вы превысили число, не должно превышать 10000")
    }
}
```

Comment: А как вы решили бы эту задачку?

Comment: Я так решил ну сказали то что не правильно, любое натуральное число должно приходить 

например

Sample Input:

234

Sample Output:

2

Comment: А вы свой код проверяли? Проверьте на числах разной длины, сразу станет видна ошибка.

Comment: да, проверял но он только работает с 4-х значным числом, а мне нужно чтобы работал 3-х значным и 2-х значным и всегда выводил первую цифру. Голову уже поломал какие только идеи не были и весь прикол в том что нужно сделать строго через условный оператор... Как бы условия задачи входит тоже

Comment: Исходное число вводится как строковый тип. Вот нафига его конвертировать в числовой тип, чтобы потом на выходе опять конвертировать в строковый? Опять же задание не предусматривает входного контроля и обработки неправильного ввода. И вообще задание противоречивое - согласно заданию, исходное число неотрицательное целое (в т.ч. возможен и ноль), но в описании входного формата оно натуральное.

Comment: я его не конвертирую в строковый тип, число идет целочисленным ввод идет после строки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Только условные операторы:

```golang
func main() {
    var a int
    fmt.Print("Введите число: ")

    fmt.Scan(&a)
    if a < 10 {
        // a = a
    } else if a < 100 {
        a = a / 10
    } else if a < 1000 {
        a = a / 100
    } else if a < 10000 {
        a = a / 1000
    } else if a == 10000 {
        a = a / 10000
    }

    fmt.Println(a);
}
```

Comment: В го можно оставлять пустой ветку if? И последнее else if проще записать как a = 1.

Comment: Не знаю - я никогда не писала на го. Я попыталась расписать алгоритм решения так, чтобы автор вопроса понял его суть. Так как он явно начинающий программист. Убрать пустые ветки if, поправить синтаксис или записать вычисления более коротко всегда можно. Главное понимать, что эти пустые ветки были, и почему они пустые. Почему можно оптимизировать вычисления в одном месте, а в другом нельзя.

Comment: благодарю, спасибо за помощь, буду знать

Comment: Мне казалось, что идеалогия гошички использовать switch case вместо if else if когда много условий.

Answer (score 2):

Можно альтернативно подойти к вопросу, как-то приблизительно так:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    i := 1234
    s := strconv.Itoa(i)
    fmt.Println(s[0:1])
}
```

```sh
$ ./gotest   
1
```

Comment: Нельзя так подойти. Язык указан и это не Python.

Comment: Точно, перепутал с go, простите :)

Comment: Работает, но сервак не пропускает. Строго через условный оператор... Как бы условия задачи входит тоже

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {
var a int
fmt.Print("Введите число: ")
fmt.Scan(&a)

int b = a; // копия чтобы не изменять число
int i=0;
for(;b>0;i++)
{
    b = b/10;
}
// i = количество знаков в числе

    a = a / power(10, (i-1)); // делим на 10 в степени i-1
    fmt.Println(a);
}
```

Comment: P.s. по условию "На вход дается натуральное число, не превосходящее 10000" и вы это проверяете, но почему-то не проверяете остальные неверные форматы, например, отрицательные числа или символы. Тут либо все нужно проверять либо ничего.

Comment: Как-то сложно..

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a int
    fmt.Println("Введите произвольное число до 10000:")
    fmt.Scan(&a)

    b := a / 1000
    c := a / 100
    d := a / 10

    if b> 0 {
        fmt.Print(b)
    } else if c >0 {
        fmt.Print(c)
    } else if d >0 {
        fmt.Print(d)
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

В Go при переводе float в int дробная часть отбрасывается. Это упрощение позволяет дойти до первой цифры числа деля его в цикле на 10 и отбрасывая дробную часть.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a int
    fmt.Scan(&a)
    
    for a > 9 {
        a /= 10
    }
    
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсивная функция
n - входное, i - максимальное круглое (10000)

```
func recur(n int, i int) {
    if n/i <= 0 {
        calc(n, i/10)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(n / i)
    }
}
```